# Importance Sampling to evaluate integral in R

Tags: r, sampling, monte-carlo, importance-sampling, numerical-integration

I have asked the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22214829/r-importance-sampling-to-solve-integrals) also.
However, there might be something wrong with my theoretical understanding hence I'm asking here as it is more relevant. Kindly do not diss without looking first.

I have referred to these links - 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060675/r-monte-carlo-integration-using-importance-sampling) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060675/r-monte-carlo-integration-using-importance-sampling). The latter link is a question of mine, but the answers, as they turn out, aren't quite right.

Hence I am creating asking a question with new attempts made to answer it.

- I have the following integral 
  $$\int_{0.01}^1 x^{-0.5}\,\text{d}x$$
  To solve this using Importance Sampling MC integration, one needs to select an **importance pdf** that is approximately the same as the **function plot**

My R code to solve the same is this :

```
#function 1 - importance sampling
w <- function(x) dunif(x,0.01,1)/dbeta(x,0.7,1)
f <- function(x) x^(-0.5)
X <- rbeta(1000,0.7,1)
Y <- w(X)*f(X)
c(mean(Y),var(Y))
```

**True integral value** - 1.8

**Using the Importance Sampling code above** - 1.82 (where my importance PDF is ***Beta(0.7,1)***

which is quite alright so I'm assuming the code is correct.

- Now I have this integral 
  $$\int_{0.3}^8 [1+\sinh(2x)\log(x)]^{-1}\text{d}x$$

for which my code is :

```
#function 2 
w <- function(x) dunif(x,0.01,1)/dnorm(x,0.5,0.25)
f <- function(x) (1+sinh(2*x)*log(x))^(-1)
X <- rnorm(1000,0.5,0.25)
Y <- w(X)*f(X)
Y <- Y[!is.na(Y)]
c(mean(Y),var(Y))
```

**True Integral Value**  ~0.7014

**Value from executing above code** ~3.25 (where my importance PDF is ***normal(0.5,sd=0.25)***

---

What am I doing wrong?

1) Take function to be evaluated as f(x).

2) Generate samples from Importance PDF g(x) that is truncated between the intervals.

3) Get the mean(f(x)/g(x)) which is the integral.

Comment: have you looked at the plot formed by the mean for each iteration (meaning for each new random value) ? You could see if you have converged yet. 1000 random values seems pretty low to me.

Comment: @Scratch - 1000 is not a good number yes but it shouldn't be significantly different, right?

For example, if 0.7 is supposed to be the answer, 0.5-0.7 is fine.

I have looked at more numbers though yes and looked at the histogram.

Comment: Well if you have tried with 100 000 and the difference is still significant, the explanation is somewhere else...

Comment: No I'm saying that the difference isn't significant when I increase the sample size . So the implementation for importance sampling might be wrong but I can't put a finger  on it .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When running the code provided for the second function I get

```
> c(mean(Y),var(Y))
[1] 3.2981238 0.5203621
> integrate(f,0.01,1)
3.19264 with absolute error < 1.1e-06
```

which means that the true value of the integral is close to 3.2, not to 0.70.

If you want to integrate `f` from 0.3 to 8, then the importance function must be

```
> w <- function(x) dunif(x,0.3,8)/dnorm(x,0.5,0.25)
```

and I changed the handling of the NA's in the problem by

```
> f <- function(x) (x>0)*(1+sinh(2*x)*log(abs(x)))^(-1)
```

which leads to

```
> Y <- w(X)*f(X)
> integrate(f,0.3,8)
2.77512 with absolute error < 2.4e-05
> integrate(f,0.3,8)$val/(8-.3)
[1] 0.3604052
```

which shows a good fit even though the Normal importance function N(0.5,0.5) may be too concentrated, i.e., it has too small a variance to cover (0.3,8) with some reasonable probability. If one changes the scale of the Normal,

```
> X <- rnorm(1e5,0.5,2.25)
> Y <- w(X)*f(X)
> c(mean(Y),var(Y))
[1] 0.3664046 1.0230197
> integrate(f,0.3,8)$va/(8-.3)
[1] 0.3604052
```

which shows a fairly good fit. When using a smaller standard deviation like $\sigma=0.1$, I find a poorer fit

```
> c(mean(Y),var(Y))
[1]   0.3370849 484.6246147
```

even when compared with $\sigma=1$:

```
> c(mean(Y),var(Y))
[1] 0.3606815 0.3232931
```

To make sense of those variations, I ran the experiment for a range of values of $\sigma$, from $0.1$ to $4$, with $10^6$ normal simulations, and got the following graph (with a log scale on the first axis)

[image]

which shows the improvement brought by large enough $\sigma$'s. And an optimum around $\sigma=0.74$.

Here is the relevant R code

```
w <- function(x) dunif(x,0.3,8)/dnorm(x,0.5,sigma) 
sigs=varz=meanz=seq(.1,4,le=50)
for (i in 1:50){
sigma=sigs[i];X=0.5+sigma*X0;Y=w(X)*f(X)
varz[i]=var(Y);meanz[i]=mean(Y)}
```